# GCP OS Patch Management fails, is the service account missing a permission?

Tags: google-compute-engine

An OS Patch Management job for a new Windows Server VM fails with status `No agent detected`.

The [gcloud os-config troublshoot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/vm-manager/verify-setup#gcloud-command) command running from PowerShell on a windows GCE VM instance responds with `GetServicePermissionDeniedException`.

```
gcloud compute os-config troubleshoot {VMINSTANCE} --zone={ZONE}
OS Config troubleshooter tool is checking if there are issues with the VM Manager setup for this VM instance.

> Is the OS Config API enabled? Unknown
The troubleshooter encountered GetServicePermissionDeniedException while checking your instance.
```

All of the manual checks on that reference page succeed.

- `osconfig.googleapis.com` is enabled for the project.
- The Google Cloud OS Config Service Agent `service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-osconfig.iam.gserviceaccount.com` has the role `Cloud OS Config Service Agent` (roles/osconfig.serviceAgent).
- The connectivity tests pass and osconfig api can be called from PowerShell.

The VM uses a custom service account with scopes = ["cloud-platform"] but no IAM roles have been granted such as roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1.

Is the custom service account missing a permission for this to work?

**[EDIT]**
Using [IAM Policy Analyser](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/analyzer) I confirmed that the custom service account has Compute Instance Admin (v1) on the target VM instance resource.

Answer (score 1):

Run the same command with debug and the exception is clear

```
gcloud compute os-config troubleshoot {VMINSTANCE} --zone={ZONE} --verbosity debug

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
serviceusage.services.get 
    googlecloudsdk.api_lib.services.exceptions.GetServicePermissionDeniedException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied to get service [osconfig.googleapis.com]
error_code=110002&service=serviceusage.googleapis.com&permission=serviceusage.services.get&resource={PROJECT}
    type: googleapis.com
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  metadata:
    permission: serviceusage.services.get
    resource: 
    service: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  reason: AUTH_PERMISSION_DENIED
```

Or

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.os-config.troubleshoot) Could not fetch resource:

- Required 'compute.projects.get' permission for 'projects/PROJECT'

Or  "permission": "osconfig.inventories.get"

So give the instance's service account these roles:

- roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer  (on the project)
- roles/compute.osLogin.
- roles/osconfig.inventoryViewer

Now the troubleshoot runs, I can see that in my case, the No agent detected issue was resolved by removing this VM metadata field:
`osconfig-disabled-features=tasks`.